# Recursion of integrated Legendre polynomials

Tags: python, recursion

[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XYDS.jpg)

I am writing these recursion in python and don't get why the official solution is different than mine.
The trivial cases for n = 1, 2 are clear.
This is my approach:

```
return ((2*(k-1)-1)*x*leg(k-1) - ((k-1)-2)*leg(k-2)) / k
```

This is the official solution:

```
return ((2*k-1)*x*leg(k-1) - (k-1)*leg(k-2)) / k
```

Why are they decreasing k to call the function, but in the first part the coefficient (2*k-1) not? And why is the coefficient in the second part changed to (k-1)?

Comment: I have a strong hunch that question is more about math (showing equivalence between an official and your derived formula) rather than programming.

Comment: The problem here is that in the past some of the official solutions were wrong. I just wanted to know if my approach is correct to translate the formula given in the image to my approach.
The formulas are not equivalent since 2*(k-1)-1 = 2*k -2 -1 = 2*k - 3 != 2*k - 1 for all k in the whole numbers, and likewise for the other coefficients.
My question is about programming, not showing mathematical proofs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

So generally, afaiu, your issue stems from the formula (in your attached image does show `L_{k+1}(x)`) while they do implement `L_{k}(x)` without the intermediate derivation that shows how to obtain `L_{k}(x)` from `L_{k+1}(x)`.

I further think that there is some confusion here, so I will sightly deviate from the notation.
Let `m = k+1` in what follows.

We then obtain through straight forward substitution:

```
m * L(x, m) = (2*(m+1)-1) * x * L(x, m-1) - ((m-1)-2) * L(x, m-2)  # for m >= 3
```

which yields

```
L(x, m) = ( (2*m + 2 - 1) * x * L(x, m-1) - ((m-3) * L(x, m-2) ) / m
```

and in python syntax, this is:

```
def L(x, m):
    if m == 1:
        return x
    elif m == 2:
        return 0.5 * (x**2 - 1)
    else:  # do this for all m >= 3
        return ( (2*m + 1) * x * L(x, m-1) - ((m-3) * L(x, m-2) ) / m
```

> Why are they decreasing k to call the function, but in the first part the coefficient (2*k-1) not?

IMHO they did, follow my derivation.

> And why is the coefficient in the second part changed to (k-1)?

I honestly do not know; to me, it seems like they made a mistake during substitution, i.e. they must have put `m+1` instead of `m-1`.

---

```
>>> (2*(k-1)-1)
```

Does first compute `k-1` multiplies it by `2` and then subtracts `1` which is indifferent from `2*k-1`. For example:

`k = 5` does yield with your solution `(2*(5-1)-1) = 7` and from the official solution `(2*5-1) = 9`.

Comment: Which of the approaches is correct?
2*(k-1)-1 = 2*k -2 -1 = 2*k - 3 != 2*k - 1 for all k

Comment: I do comply with the official one.

Sources: [Link1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-legendre-polynomials-using-recursion-relation/)
[Link 2](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/py_src/legendre_polynomial/legendre_polynomial.html)
[Link3](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/special/orthogonal.py#L2042-L2094)

Comment: They are using a different formula here, which is for the Legendre Polynomials. I comply in this case with the official solution too:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-legendre-polynomials-using-recursion-relation/

Comment: My exercises requires to calculate the integrated(!) Legendre polynomials with a different given formula, like in the attached imaged. I cannot understand how to get from these formula to the solution. I wrote it down on a paper for k = 3, 4 and the official solution gives different results than expected. Now I assume they used the formula for Legendre polynomials instead of the formula of integrated Legendre polynomials. Could you please have a look at the image just to be sure if it complies with the official solution?

Comment: What I understand, is that all k have to be reduced by one, to get from L_(k+1) to L_k. But there is any obvious system in the official formula, since in one case they reduce it, and in the other one not...

Comment: @displayname I have updated my answer, please check the EDIT section.

Comment: Thank you very much for the taken effort and confirming that the official solution has a mistake!
In the first part, you substituted k wrong, because if m = k+1, then k = m-1 != m+1. For this reason your first part resembles the official solution, but it should be wrong. The second part is like I have done it!
Thank you Thomas!

Comment: @displayname Thanks for pointing out my mistake in the first substitution! Do you want me to keep the (unintentional) irony within this answer or shall I fix it? ;) Also, may I ask you to accept my provided solution in case it did help you?

Comment: It is not necessary to fix it, since my question is answered! I accepted your solution, but need to get some more reputation points. I just registered today to ask this question. Regards from Düsseldorf!

"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Thank you! Greetings from Frankfurt am Main! ;)